# Remember language with no content-languages site

Tags: joomla-3.x, language, multilingual

Hello I'm developing a website that has not content languages, it would be some kind of joomla administrator, only language strings are loaded (no contents needed for this website). I want that Joomla remembers the last language selected.

Example:

- **mywebsite.com** -> default language (en-GB)
- **mywebsite.com?language=es-ES**  -> now I see the es-ES strings loaded
- **mywebsite.com** -> again the website loads the default language (en-GB)

I want to display it in es-ES, I mean keep the latest language selected. I don't want to define content languages as I need to be

I guess I need to add the es-ES language variable again and again, maybe a is there a plugin that does so?

Regards

Comment: Keep the latest language selected or always Spanish? Why don't you want to define content languages? With the System Plugin:Language Filter, there will be a cookie stored for the language selection. You can set cookie duration to 1 year.

Comment: Keep the latest language selected. To use language filter I have to set content languages which is not useful in this case. I don't have different content versions of the website, only interested in loading language strings. I don't want to define content languages because I don't want the to be attached in SEF urls

Comment: Think that one way or another, you need a multilingual site - even if you only want to load language strings. Multilingual sites need content languages, so setting languages is still useful.

Comment: But language is remembered when user is logged-in (for example in Joomla administrator, no need for content languages), this should be possible with anonymous session also

Comment: I don't think this is true. How did you come to this conclusion? Language for logged-in users comes from saved settings in the db.

Comment: OK. I can see the best way is to set content languages. Now I have the opposite question: what about avoid redirecting to the content language for a defined menu itemId. For example: mysite.com/en/control-panel?vars=etc + mysite.com/api?vars=etc

Comment: Found the solution, just activated "Remove URL Language Code" from plugin options. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @xavip When you are able to self-solve, please take the time to write up a complete and educational answer, then award your answer the big green tick so that the system deems this page to be resolved